# In a help on moderators, it seems that only mods can protect questions

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, moderators, help-center, protected-questions

> Moderators also have some **special abilities** necessary to handle those rare exceptional conditions:
>
> - ...
> - Moderators can protect questions. Protected questions only allow answers by users with more than 10 reputation.
> - ...

From this help (https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) seems that only mods can protect questions, what is not true, however: questions also can be protected by users, having 15k reps.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

But all moderators, no matter their reputation score, can protect questions.

Just because *all* moderators have these special abilities it doesn't mean *only* moderators have these special abilities.  They are special, as not everybody can protect a question...

So there you go.

Not much else to say here.  Hmmm...

I know what to do.  Add a funny image.  Yeah.

[image: Hello, I'm Miley Cyrus as a bear. Please don't judge me. I'm just a bear being a bear.]

Comment: Moderators have access to every privilege granted by rep, regardless of their rep.  Why call out just protecting?  Why not mention being able to see deleted posts, or being able to edit without requiring review?

Comment: @Servy uh, dunno, answering the question?

Comment: That's essentially what this question is asking though.  Why is protecting called out when it's no different than every other non-mod privilege?

Comment: @Servy You might be reading more into it.  Seems like he's asking why it says it is a **special ability** of mods, whereas it is in fact just a **special ability** of a subset of users.  Which is what it is.  The only reason to point it out is that mods can do it at any rep.  That's why it's listed as a special ability of mods even though reg users can do it, if they have enough rep.

Comment: And that applies to *every single privilege on the site*.  If the goal of the page is to call out the fact that mods have access to all non-mod privileges regardless of their rep, then why doesn't it say *that* instead of only calling out protecting, which is in no way unique?

Comment: Because crisscross applesauce.  Maybe you should edit the OP to have the question say that?  Or would that be too radical a change?  Look, I'm just here to find reasons to compare Miley with a bear.  And possibly answer questions based on the text they actually contain.  I'm not a perfect man.  Don't judge.

Comment: "I know what to do. Add a funny image." - thats why I like your posts and can't resist giving you **+1** :)

Comment: Won't is right: protecting questions is a "special ability" even if it's available to another subset of users as well. That section doesn't say that **only** mods have that ability...I don't see a problem with the current language. (And it's not a bug, that list of special abilities was taken directly from the seminal [Theory of Moderation blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/).)

Comment: Okay, jagoffs, anonymous downvoters (OMG Y U NO LEAVE REASON) and deletevoters--look up.  An employee of SE says I'm right.  Nyah.

Comment: I'll accept your answer because it score of -5 what does mean agreement of the community.

Comment: @nicael if you think the answer is correct, then do what you feel is best.  I think they just hate my swag, and so downvote.